# OMNET++ - How to prioritize UDP over TCP

Tags: tcp, udp, omnet++, traffic

Hello i'm new with omnet++ and networking simulations, i  have the following network:

```
import inet.common.misc.NetAnimTrace;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;
import ned.DatarateChannel;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.ethernet.Eth100M;
import inet.node.inet.Router;
import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;
import inet.node.inet.WirelessHost;
import inet.node.wireless.AccessPoint;
import inet.physicallayer.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.contract.IIntegratedVisualizer;




network clienteServer
{
@display("bgb=500,300");
submodules:
    visualizer: <default("IntegratedCanvasVisualizer")> like IIntegratedVisualizer if hasVisualizer() {
        parameters:
            @display("p=100,50");
    }
    configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
        parameters:
            assignDisjunctSubnetAddresses = false;
            @display("p=100,150");
    }
    radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium {
        parameters:
            @display("p=100,250");
    }
    TCP1: WirelessHost {
        parameters:
            @display("p=186,178");
    }
    UDP1: WirelessHost {
        parameters:
            @display("p=193,77");
    }
    Server: WirelessHost {
        parameters:
            @display("p=438,122");
    }


    accessPoint: AccessPoint {
        parameters:
            @display("p=315,108");
    }
    UDP2: WirelessHost {
        parameters:
            @display("p=255,30");
    }


}
```

and my .ini file, is the following, is very simple

```
[General]
network = clienteServer
total-stack = 7MiB
tkenv-plugin-path = ../../../etc/plugins
debug-on-errors = true
record-eventlog = true

**.addDefaultRoutes = false

**.UDP1.numUdpApps = 10
**.UDP1.udpApp[*].typename = "UDPVideoStreamCli"
**.UDP1.udpApp[*].serverAddress = "Server"
**.UDP1.udpApp[*].serverPort = 1000


**.UDP2.numUdpApps = 1
**.UDP2.udpApp[*].typename = "UDPBasicApp"
**.UDP2.udpApp[*].destAddresses = "Server"
**.UDP2.udpApp[*].messageLength = 1000B
**.UDP2.udpApp[*].sendInterval = 12ms




**.Server.numUdpApps = 1
**.Server.udpApp[*].typename = "UDPVideoStreamSvr"
**.Server.udpApp[*].localPort = 1000
 **.Server.udpApp[*].sendInterval = 10ms
**.Server.udpApp[*].packetLen = 2000B
**.Server.udpApp[*].videoSize = 100000B

**.TCP1.numTcpApps = 1
**.TCP1.tcpApp[*].typename = "TelnetApp"
**.TCP1.tcpApp[0].localAddress = ""
**.TCP1.tcpApp[0].localPort = -1
**.TCP1.tcpApp[0].connectAddress = "Server"
**.TCP1.tcpApp[0].connectPort = 1000


**.TCP1.tcpApp[0].startTime = 0
**.TCP1.tcpApp[0].commandLength = exponential(10B)
**.TCP1.tcpApp[0].commandOutputLength = exponential(5B)
**.TCP1.tcpApp[0].thinkTime = truncnormal(1s,2s)
**.TCP1.tcpApp[0].idleInterval = 10ms
**.TCP1.tcpApp[0].reconnectInterval = 3s
**.TCP1.tcpApp[0].dataTransferMode = "object"


**.Server.numTcpApps = 1
**.Server.tcpApp[*].typename = "TCPGenericSrvApp"
**.Server.tcpApp[0].localAddress = ""
**.Server.tcpApp[0].localPort = 1000
**.Server.tcpApp[0].replyDelay = 0








**.initialZ = 0


**.scalar-recording = true
**.vector-recording = true
```

As you can see, i only have 4 host, one that acts like a server, 2 UDP ones and one that send TCP msgs, How can i prioritize udp traffic over tcp, in a simple way, any suggestions please??

Comment: Without adjusting the UDP/TCP traffic generator (application) parameters you mean? There is no underlying scheduler used anywhere, correct? You would need some traffic shaping module in the AccessPoint, if the traffic from the sending stations gets transmitted over the AccessPoint to the Server, which I assume you are modeling here, correct?

Comment: @MichaelKirsche yes that's correct, the traffics goes through the access point and reach the server-host

Comment: So traffic is passed through the access point on layer 2, without some kind of traffic shaper or scheduler who understands the payload of layer 2 (IP, UDP, TCP), there is no way to prioritize UDP against TCP.

Comment: Maybe you can check if there are ways to prioritize your traffic on layer 2 with some field or MAC-related mechanism, no idea though at the moment.